# Change text and image on mouseclick/mouseover in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I figured out how to change image on mouseover through javascript. But unable to figure how to add description below the image on mouseover/mouseclick on respective image. I'm not good at jQuery. Please help me in solving the problem in javascript only.

```
<html>

 <head>
  <style>
     .imgStyle {
         height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            border: 3px solid grey;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
   <img src="img/img_01.jpg" id="mainImage" />

   <div id="describ01" style="display:none">Description 01</div>
   <div id="describ02" style="display:none">Description 02</div>
   <div id="describ03" style="display:none">Description 03</div>
   <div id="describ04" style="display:none">Description 04</div>
   <br />
    <div id="myDiv" onmouseover="changeImage(event)">
       <img src="img/img_02.jpg" class="imgStyle" />
       <img src="img/img_03.jpg" class="imgStyle" />
       <img src="img/img_04.jpg" class="imgStyle" />
       <img src="img/img_05.jpg" class="imgStyle" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function changeImage(event) {
        event = event || window.event;

         var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

        if(targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
       document.getElementById("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
        }
       }
     </script>
   </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript then the answer will be

```
document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = 'Hello World';
```

and if you want to use JQuery then

```
 $("#description").html("Hello World");
```

Hopefully it will help you

Comment: Please try the above code. When I place the mouse cursor on any one of four images in myDiv then the main image gets replaced with the hovered image.

Comment: The code you mentioned will be helpful in adding manually. But i want both text and image need to be generated on mouse hover.

Comment: I know this is possible with css display property. But unable to figure out how to blend in javascript.

Comment: I updated the code. Please take a look at the problem i'm facing

Comment: ok so you want to show and hide the text when mouse is over and focus.. ? m i right

Comment: Yes. With respect to the image hovered or clicked.

Comment: Ok so write the code i mentioned above after the folllowing line

'document.getElementById("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");'

this will change the text of the div when mouse is over on the image

Comment: no dude. It's not working. The same content is appearing on all images got replaced when hovered. I want different individual text for each image

Comment: ahh..  then use if statement in the mouseover method ... check the image name in condition and then change the values of div according to the image..

like if (targetElement.getAttribute("src")=="img/img_02.jpg")
{
/chenge the description divs values using jquery
}
else if (targetElement.getAttribute("src")=="img/img_03.jpg)
{
// chenge the description according to that to that image name
}


i hope this will help yoiu

Answer (score 0):

Give each of your images a data attribute:

```
<img src="img/img_02.jpg" class="imgStyle" data-text='text goes here' />
```

Then use this on hover:

```
if(targetElement.tagName == "IMG") {
  document.getElementById("mainImage").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
  document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = this.getAttribute("data-text");
};
```

Now you only need one description div as before.

Comment: I updated the code. Please take a look and help me. I was unable to figure how to blend it with the image changing function i'm using.

Comment: Replace the if statement as above

Comment: Here from the above solution you shared I was able to update same description on all image that got replaced. I want individual description for each image.

Comment: Above is a more effective solution for what you want.